# Finishing a executeServices not working

Tags: java, ping

im using this code from one guy here in stack:

```
package test;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Pinger {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Pinger pinger = new Pinger();
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                frame.setSize(300, 400);
                frame.add(panel);
                JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
                panel.add(textArea);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                pinger.executor.execute(pinger.createRunnable("google.com",
                        textArea));
            }
        });

    }

    private Runnable createRunnable(final String ip, final JTextArea area) {
        return new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                String resposta = "";
                String comando = "ping -t " + ip;

                try {
                    Scanner S = new Scanner(Runtime.getRuntime().exec(comando)
                            .getInputStream());
                    while (S.hasNextLine()) {
                        final String newText = S.nextLine();
                        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                area.setText(area.getText()
                                        + System.getProperty("line.separator")
                                        + newText);
                            }
                        });

                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };
    }

    Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

}
```

it work Perfect, buttt the

pinger.executor.shutdown(); dont work, the textArea still get the ping response, and the PING.exe, conhost.exe still in process list, i have to finish it manually or there is a way to auto kill the process attached to the runnable?

Comment: What happens if you exit(0)?

Comment: it works, but i dont want to close the program everytime man... why -1?

Comment: @user905374 -1 and no answer?

Comment: I did not downvote you. I only asked what happens when you exit(0)

Comment: @user905374 when i close the program, it finish correctly

Comment: Why not assign the `Process` object to a member variable, then use `process.destroy()` when you need to stop it?

Comment: @Tap no idea how to do it :/ have some example?

Comment: When do you want it to stop?  When the window is closed, when the jvm exits, all of the above?

Comment: @Tap, when i press a STOP button, when the Windows Close its alright stopping correctly, but i want to put a STOP BUTTON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the process to a member variable, then call its `destroy` method when the stop button is clicked.

```
public class Pinger {

    protected Process process;

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                final Pinger pinger = new Pinger(); // Pinger must be final for access by anonymous class below
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                frame.setSize(300, 400);
                frame.add(panel);
                JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();

                // Create the stop button and handle the client event
                JButton stop = new JButton();
                stop.setText("Stop");
                stop.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                        try {
                            pinger.process.destroy();
                        } catch (Exception e){}                        
                    }
                    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {}
                    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {}
                    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {}
                    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {}
                });
                panel.add(stop);
                panel.add(textArea);


                frame.setVisible(true);
                pinger.executor.execute(pinger.createRunnable("google.com",
                        textArea));
            }
        });

    }

    private Runnable createRunnable(final String ip, final JTextArea area) {
        return new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            String resposta = "";
            String comando = "ping -t " + ip;

            try {
                // assign the new process object to your instance variable
                process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(comando);
                Scanner S = new Scanner(process.getInputStream());
                while (S.hasNextLine()) {
                    final String newText = S.nextLine();
                    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            area.setText(area.getText()
                                    + System.getProperty("line.separator")
                                    + newText);
                        }
                    });

                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };
}

Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

}
```

Comment: worked fine, i used only this and worked: `btnParar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    
    process.destroy();
   }
  }); `

Comment: Glad to hear it!  Thanks.